# Pandas Dataframe to Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to dump a table from a MySQL database and upload it to a bucket.

I dealt with the connection, selected the table and transform it into a Pandas Dataframe.

So, I would like to upload this df to Cloud Storage. I did read about a [/tmp](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#local_disk) on Cloud Functions environment, but I need to write it on disk before to send to GCS? Can I upload it directly to the bucket without saving locally?

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="host", user="user", passwd="passwd", database="database")

mycursor = mydb.cursor(named_tuple=True)
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-bucket")
blob = bucket.blob("file.csv")
```

Testing on my laptop I do the following:

```
df.to_csv("file.csv")
blob.upload_from_filename("file.csv")
```

It works but seems not the best way on Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in that way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult).to_csv(sep=";", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="UTF-8")
blob.upload_from_string(data=df)
```