# mySQL export to GCP cloud-storage

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I have mySQL running on-prem and would like to migrate it with mySQL running on Cloud SQL (GCP). I first want to export tables to Cloud Storage as JSON files and then from there move them to mySQL (cloud-sql) & Big Query.
Now I wonder how I should do this - export each table as JSON or just dump the whole database to cloud storage? (we might need to change schemas for some tables that's why im thinking to do it 1 by 1).
Is there any way doing it with python pandas?
I found this --> [Pandas Dataframe to Cloud Storage Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940430/pandas-dataframe-to-cloud-storage-bucket)
but don't understand how to connect this to my GCP's cloud storage, and how to do this `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")` for all my tables.

EDIT 1:
so i came up with this, but this works only for the selected schema + table. how can I do this for all tables in the schema??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os
import csv

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/python2/key.json"
#export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/python2/key.json"
#credentials = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/home/python2/key.json')
#credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost", user="root", passwd="pass_word", database="test")

mycursor = mydb.cursor(named_tuple=True)
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-buckets-1234567")
blob = bucket.blob("file.json")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult).to_json(orient='records')
#df = pd.DataFrame(data=myresult).to_csv(sep=";", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="UTF-8")
blob.upload_from_string(data=df)
```

Comment: Do you want to have the same database on Cloud SQL? And then modernize/update them (maybe by splitting it, partly on BigQuery, the rest on Cloud SQL)?

Comment: i am going to have all the tables on my cloud sql and some of them will go on the big query for the analytics team.

Comment: Did you have a loook to database migration tool? If so, why does it not match your requirement? https://cloud.google.com/database-migration

Comment: Because I want first to have all the data from the other company on my cloud storage and then from my cloud storage import the specific tables to already running cloud sql + big query. I think the migration tool creates new cloud sql no? and it takes full dump?

Comment: IMO, it's easier to first migrate in the Cloud, and then to export your data to Cloud Storage, with BigQuery (with a connection from BigQuery to Cloud SQL to query the data and then export them to Cloud Storage) or directly with the Cloud SQL export feature. Even if your first Cloud SQL instance is a temporary instance.

Comment: you mean it's easier because there's the Migration tool?

Comment: Yes, the migration, with the migration tool allows you to easily move the data in the cloud. Then, Cloud SQL feature are natively integrated with Cloud Storage and exporting data are very easy, a simple API call is enough to achieve what you want!, It's out of the box!